# Rails 5 not loading encrypted secrets in production.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a project configured to use Rails encrypted secrets.  Everything works fine until I try to access a secret within the `production.rb` environment file.

I found that if I try to access something like `Rails.application.secrets.smtp_user_name` within the configure block it wipes out all of the encrypted secrets (I'm only left with things in `secrets.yml` ... which I'm not using).  Example:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 5.1.2)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.secrets
=> {:secret_key_base=>nil, :secret_token=>nil}
```

If I remove the attempt to access the secrets it works correctly:

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.secrets
=> {:secret_key_base=>"...", :smtp_user_name=>"...", :smtp_password=>"...", :secret_token=>nil}
```

I'm currently working around it by using two configure blocks in `production.rb` as follows:

```
# This is hacky, it needs to come before the second configure block where
# the encrypted secrets are used.
Rails.application.configure do
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true
end

Rails.application.configure do
 ... stuff that uses Rails.application.secrets, like ActionMailer
end
```

Anybody else faced this and possibly have a more correct way to work around it?

It makes sense why this is happening (Rails doesn't know to load the encrypted secrets because we haven't told it to you), but I'm thinking there must be a better way to deal with it.

**Update**

This nailed me again 9 months later.  To be clear, if you reference `Rails.application.secrets` BEFORE calling `config.read_encrypted_secrets = true` you will cache empty secrets and not be able to access any of the values in `secrets.yml.enc`!

In my case I had tried to configure Paperclip S3 credentials in `application.rb` while my `config.read_encrypted_secrets = true` was set in `production.rb`. Result was `devise.rb` blowing up trying to read a secret for the key base, all because in `application.rb` I had effectively cached nil secrets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is bug report related to your issue:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30362#issuecomment-326821656

In general even if you have all things set up properly you need check also **order** how your application loads secrets. If your application ask first for `Rails.application.secrets` and then set proper flag... `Rails.application.secrets` will cache version without secrets... and Secrets from `secret.yml.enc` will not be merge.